# How to search for equal variables in rows (in a smart way) and store according rows as subsets?

Tags: r

I have a huge data frame. One column is an integer ranging from 1 to 2.
What I need is a way to look for continous rows with a number of certain values in this column, subset these rows and process them later into graphs.

I attached a small example, which does at least some of the desired work:
I am able to print out the subsets I am looking for. But two questions remain:

- I guess there are way smarter methods in R then to apply a "for" loop over the complete data.frame. Any hints?
- Which command do I have to put in where now the "print" command is to store the temporary data.frame? I guess I need a list due to the differing length of the subsets...

I already had a look at aggregate or ddply, but could not come up with a solution.

Any help is highly appreciated.

```
test<-c(rep(1,3),rep(2,5),rep(1,3),rep(2,3),rep(1,3),rep(2,8),rep(1,3)) 
letters<-c("a","b","c","d")
a1<-as.data.frame(cbind(test,letters))

BZ<-2   #The variable to look for
n_BZ=4  #The number of minimum appearences

k<-1  # A variable to be used as a list item index in which the subset will be stored

for (i in 2:nrow(a1)){
  if (a1$test[i-1]!=BZ & a1$test[i]==BZ)      # When "test" BECOMES "2"
    {t_temp<-a1[i,]}                            #... start writing a temporary array
  else if (a1$test[i-1]==BZ & a1$test[i]==BZ) # When "test" REMAINS "2"
    {t_temp<-rbind(t_temp,a1[i,])}              #... continue writing a temporary array 
  else if (a1$test[i-1]==BZ & a1$test[i]!=BZ) # When "test" ENDS BEING "2"
    {if (nrow(t_temp)>n_BZ)                     #... check if the temporary array has more rows then demanded
      {print(t_temp)                              #... print the array (desired: put the array to a list item k)
       k<-k+1}}                                   #... increase k
    else                                      # If array too small
    {t_temp<-NULL}                              # reset
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `rle` function is really handy for stuff like this. It takes an atomic vector and returns a `list` with elements `lengths` and `values`, where `lengths` contains the run length of each value in `values`.

Since the call to `cbind` in your example coerces the `test` column to `factor`, I first converted it to `numeric`:

```
a1 <- within(a1, test <- as.numeric(as.character(test)))
```

Then the result can be obtained in a nice (essentially) one-liner:

```
with(rle(a1$test),
    split(a1, rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))[values == BZ & lengths >= n_BZ]
)
```

Comment: @Jochen if this worked for you, don't for get to close the question by accepting the answer.

Comment: Hey, just tested it and it does EXACTLY what I was looking for. I will now get my brain around how it works...Thank you once again, Gavin!